# Java, replace values in a list

Tags: java, list

I have following problem. I want to take a list with a method, find a value within that list and replace it with another.

```
void replaceAll( ArrayList<Integer> arr, Integer toFind, Integer replacement) {
   int indexOfArray = arr.indexOf(toFind);
   if(arr.contains(toFind)) {
      for(int x = 0; x < arr.size(); x++) {
         if (arr.contains(toFind)) {
            arr.remove(toFind);
            arr.add(indexOfArray, replacement);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

This is the solution I have worked out for myself and it most certainly works. However, I think it can be done more cleanly without the usage of a for loop. Could someone tell me how?

Comment: If this code works fine, then this question is off topic on Stack Overflow, but may be good for our sister site [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Can't test it on my tablet, but what about `List#replaceAll` with a ternary operator in the UnaryOperator?

Answer (score 9):

There is a built in method to do exactly this operation:

```
Collections.replaceAll(list, foo, bar);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Java 8 with all the power of lambdas, simply do:

```
void
replaceAll (ArrayList<Integer> list, Integer i1, Integer i2)
{
  list.replaceAll ((x) => (x.equals (i1) ? i2 : x));
}
```

You might also want to read about [java.util.stream.Stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html)

Comment: In Java, the arrow operator is '->' not '=>'. This could be written in Java as list.replaceAll((x->x.equals(i1)?i2:x);

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it with a `ListIterator`:

```
ListIterator<Integer> it = list.listIterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
  if (it.next().equals(toFind)) {
    it.set(replacement);
  }
}
```

For an `ArrayList`, this is little different to getting/setting elements by index; but it is generally more efficient for non-`RandomAccess` lists, e.g. if you wanted apply it to a `LinkedList`.

Answer (score 0):

I would use two `List` methods `indexOf` to get index of element to replace and `set` to replace old element with new one:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        String newString = null, oldString = null;
        list.set(list.indexOf(oldString), newString);
```